# Android Fragment Data Pass with TABBED Activity

Tags: android

When i try to retrieve category list from server for multiple tab, after set adapter its Toast two ID for the first time .Suppose, When current tab id  is ZERO , then its showing next increment ID .[image]

Like the Screenshot its showing 20 in tab 0 .

Basically i want  the category id dynamically when i swipe the tab.

```
public class Tabtest extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    int i;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabtest);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);

        getCategoriesList();


        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    public void getCategoriesList(){
        Retrofit retrofit = newsClient.getClient();
        apiNews service = retrofit.create(apiNews.class);
        Call<List<Category>> call = service.categorriesList();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Category>> call, Response<List<Category>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    for (int i=0;i<response.body().size();i++){
                            MenuBurgersFragment pageFragment=  new MenuBurgersFragment();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            adapter.addFragment(pageFragment, response.body().get(i).getId()+"");
                            bundle.putString("welcome", response.body().get(i).getId()+"" );
                            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                            pageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Category>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Tabtest.this, "safsavas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_list_items, container, false);

        bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            storeText = bundle.getString("welcome");
            Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), storeText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In View Pager Bydefault previous and next fragment data is loaded that's why you got next fragment value in toast .

In that you have to set OffscreenPageLimit in viewpager to restrict to load previous and next fragment in View Pager
set value of setOffscreenPageLimit() is 1 .

Hope that above will help you.